# dynamic import js, but have a single css file

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm using webpack 4 with an esmodule based react app. We use css modules with less. When I pack my app with dynamic imports my css is also chunked to multiple files. I'd like to use the dynamic imports to lazy load the js, but keep all the css together in 1 file. I've tried using the following, but it does not seem to work.

```
optimization: {
                splitChunks: {
                    cacheGroups: {
                        styles: {
                            name: 'styles',
                            test: /\.(css|less)$/,
                            chunks: 'all'
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
```

Comment: so it appears that the minicssextract plugin creates another js file that must be loaded for everything to work.